# How to use OR operator in CASE THEN statement

Tags: t-sql, case

I have a situation like this

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where col1 = case when (booleanexp1) then a OR col1 = b 
                  when (booleanexp1) then c OR col1 = d end
```

I mean I need to get `where col1 = a or col1 = b` when booleanexp1 is TRUE,
but I get a syntax error? How is the right way to perform something like this?

Comment: Do not forget to check that your `booleanexp1` can NOT be NULL... or you can loose the third option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two `booleanexp1`s is a misprint:

```
select col1, col2
from table1
where ((booleanexp1) AND (col1 IN (a, b)))
   or ((booleanexp2) AND (col1 IN (c, d)))
```

PS. `not (booleanexp1)` is one possible option of `(booleanexp2)`...

Answer (score -3):

```
select col1, col2
 from table1
where col1 = case 
               when (booleanexp1)  OR col1 = b  then a
               when (booleanexp1)  OR col1 = d  then c end
```

This part is also a boolean expression

Comment: Code-only answers aren't really seen as acceptable here - as such I've downvoted this answer. Could you add more comments to explain why your code solves the OP's question?>